# Combining objects according to attribute fields whose output Area field is equal to the input. Help me, please!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.7

Input Feature: EXAM_region with field Area sum = 4814.34
[image]
I tried with tool Dissolve: Output Feature class must not have multi part geometries.
[image]
EXAM_region_Dissolve with field Area sum = 10876.77 wrong with input 4814.34

My data file and workflow: http://www.mediafire.com/file/qwoql6vdxliloqb/Data.rar/file

Comment: You have this tagged arcgis-10.2 *and* arcgis-10.7.  Which is it?

Comment: I thought it was an error and tried both versions, but the results were the same!